# Why Menu items are not coming in IE10 using Extjs 4.1?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have done application using ExtJs 4, contains feature menu. Menu items are showing nicely in all browser like IE9, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. But issue is coming when launch the same app in IE10 menu not showing menu items. when inspect the element menu it contains menu items data. Can anybody tell me why it is not displaying in IE10? How to showcase menu items data. i am adding dynamically items menu by using the reference of items. below is my code.

```
refs:[
    {
         ref: 'region',
         selector: 'globalNavigationView > button[name="btnFilter"] > menuitem[text="Region"]'
    },
```

**Within FunCalling**
Here regionValue contains list of items.

```
this.getRegion().menu.removeAll();

dynamicRegion=new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<regionValue.length; i++){
            var objSubR=new Object();
            objSubR.cls= 'filterMenuCls';
            objSubR.text=regionValue[i];
            dynamicRegion.push(objSubR);
        }

this.getRegion().menu.add(dynamicRegion);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext JS 4.1 does not support IE10, 4.2 does.